# convert BigDecimal to Scientific Notation Java

Tags: java

How do i print this in scientific notation:

```
BigDecimal r= (a.subtract(exact, MathContext.DECIMAL128)).divide(exact, MathContext.DECIMAL128).stripTrailingZeros();
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(format.format(r));
```

where:

```
a = 1.111111111111111160454356650006957352161407470703125
exact = 0.11
```

returns:

```
r = 0.900010000000000004
```

any ideas? I've also tried calling EngineeringString() on the BigDecimal but this also didn't seem to work for me

Comment: What exactly do you want to produce? A BigDecimal or a String? If a BigDecimal, do you want it to have a specific format for its toString()? Please show the output you *want*.

Comment: Guessing on this one, but couldn't you probably cast it to a double which is printed in scientific notation already

Comment: @Bohemian either or, it can be a string or a BigDecimal.. just need scientific notation

Comment: Also, what **data type** is `exact`?

Comment: @BlueMonster there is no such thing as a "BigDecimal in scientific notation". It is just a bunch of bits, not a human readable thing... What zou want is a formatted string in scientific notation - as what my answer does...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overdid the thing. What you only need is:

```
System.out.println(format.format(r));
```

The [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object *does indeed* create a string, creating a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instance again would just parse the number from string again - and the toString() method is called on the BigDecimal instance, produing the output you described...

**Some clarification**

`BigDecimal`, and other numeric formats (and dates too!) are stored in binary formats in the memory, abstracted from how us, humans think of them. `BigDecimal` for example stores the decimal digits, and where the decimal point is. [Floating point numbers are even more sophisticated.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) stores the seconds from [*The Epoch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch). You need to *format* them to be readable. Formatting means to create a String (or semantically similar)  object, that represents the value of the given object in the desired format. This doesn't involve changing the original object in any way.

The default formatting, toString() provides one generic format. To get your output the way you'd like does not mean to change the value to be formatted right with toString(), but to transform the unchanged value into the right String. Nice example is Double.toString() (using sun.mic.FloatingDecimal): it does exponential notation when the number is large or small enough, but in between, it prints in plain decimal format...